# how to doing a list of date and time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i have this code to generate a list from two variables that are the input parameters and the function return a list of date and time with all dates and times between the input parameters

```
FechaIn = "2019-01-01 00:00"
FechaFin = "2019-01-16 23:59"
meses = []
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(FechaIn, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(FechaFin, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
date_array = \
    (start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days))
for date_object in date_array:
    meses.append(str(date_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")))
meses.append(FechaFin)
print (meses)
```

The code return that:

```
['2019-01-01 00:00', '2019-01-02 00:00', '2019-01-03 00:00', '2019-01-04 00:00', '2019-01-05 00:00', '2019-01-06 00:00', '2019-01-07 00:00', '2019-01-08 00:00', '2019-01-09 00:00', '2019-01-10 00:00', '2019-01-11 00:00', '2019-01-12 00:00', '2019-01-13 00:00', '2019-01-14 00:00', '2019-01-15 00:00', '2019-01-16 23:59']
```

But i need generate with all hours, like that:

```
['2019-01-01 00:00', '2019-01-01 00:01', '2019-01-01 00:02', '2019-01-01 00:03', ...]
```

Comment: Instead of iterating hourly - iterate minute-ly using the dupes code

Comment: You can easily do this with pandas, `pd.date_range(start, end, freq='H')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep another datetime object as the tracker, adding one minute at a time, appending it to the meses list. You stop when the tracker datetime equals the end time, and make sure to append the end time as well if you want the list to be inclusive of the start and end dates.

```
FechaIn = "2019-01-01 00:00"
FechaFin = "2019-01-16 23:59"
meses = []
start = now = datetime.datetime.strptime(FechaIn, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(FechaFin, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
while now != end:
    meses.append(str(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")))
    now += datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
meses.append(FechaFin)
print (meses)
```

Output:

```
['2019-01-01 00:00', '2019-01-01 00:01', '2019-01-01 00:02' ... '2019-01-16 23:57', '2019-01-16 23:58', '2019-01-16 23:59']
```